# RecyclerView - quick preload of a lot of items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created a recycler view with thumbnails generating in real time. My problem is that I need to preload 50 items (thumbnails) ahead  of the currently visible ones and I can't seem to find the appropriate way of doing so.

I know that preloading can be done with `getExtraLayoutSpace()` from `LinearLayoutManager` but it doesn't work for me. If you look at this extra layout space implementation in the Android code, you'll see that it is a space available only in the scrolling direction. When changing the scroll direction, all of the items required to be preloaded in the new direction are prepared and the old ones are not available anymore. This causes a very noticeable hang when changing scroll directions in my case since I am trying to preload a lot of items - 50. I am doing the loading of a thumbnail in a separate thread but all the items are layouted obviously on the UI thread (which seems to cause the hang).

I am also NOT interested in third party libraries because I've written a lot of code making everything work with the basic implementation of recycler view and I don't have time for a lot of refactoring.

Do you know of any other ways of preloading items in `RecyclerView`? Maybe somehow tweaking the `LinearLayoutManager`? I sure hope you know of a good way, so I can evade implementing elaborate caching of thumbnails.